# Не применяется text-shadow

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Не применяется text-shadow на span. Пробовал применить на весь абзац - не работает. На фото -как должно быть[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<style>
         span {
           display: inline;
           font-family: 'Montserrat';
           font-style: normal;
           font-weight: 600;
           font-size: 70px;
           line-height: 140%;
           text-align: center;
           color: #EDE574;
           text-shadow:  2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(93, 102, 81, 0.26) inset;
          }
      </style>
      <p><span>190</span> руб/м2</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать фон под цвет текста, а потом показывать его вместе с тенью только там, где размещен текст (Photoshop знаете? там есть инструмент "маска", здесь тоже самое)

```html
<style> 
    span {
        background-color: #EDE574;
        color: transparent;
        text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -moz-background-clip: text;
        background-clip: text;
        font-family: 'Montserrat';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 70px;
        line-height: 140%;
        text-align: center;          
}
</style>

<p><span>190</span>руб/м2</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

SPAN имеет собственный бэкграунд-цвет. Поэтому и не работает. Пропишите так:
(убрать цвет заднего фона)

```
span {
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 70px;
    line-height: 140%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #EDE574;
    background-color: transparent;  <-----    !!!
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); 
   }
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но ваш вариант у меня выдал обычную тень, а не внутреннюю

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй прописать фон спану прозрачный и вырезать текст, вот пример :

```
<style>
     span {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ede574b8;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(255 255 255);
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 70px;
    line-height: 140%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
      }
  </style>
```